# Assert.Equal() fails when comparing IEnumerable (using yield return) with itself

Tags: c#, ienumerable, xunit

Ran into the following issue when writing a unit test for my code. Why does the Assert.Equal() fail when comparing an IEnumerable with itself?

```
private class ReferenceType { }

[Fact]
public void EnumerableEqualityTest()
{
    IEnumerable<ReferenceType> GetEnumerable()
    {
        yield return new ReferenceType();
    }

    var enumerable = GetEnumerable();

    Assert.Equal(enumerable, enumerable); // fails
}
```

Comment: Use `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` in order to compare collections.

Comment: Or `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` if order is important.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The test is using xUnit. CollectionAssert is for NUnit. Can it compare enumerables using yield return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what is going on we need to understand what `Assert.Equal()` is actually doing. According to the documentation of `Assert.Equal<T>(IEnumerable<T> expected, IEnumerable<T> actual)` it "Verifies that two sequences are equivalent, using a default comparer".

The `Assert.Equal()` in this case iterates the enumerable to check if the individual values are equal. This means that the enumerable is iterated twice for the comparison and that a new instance of `ReferenceType` is created each time (through yield return). The test fails since the default comparer for a reference type only checks if the instances refer to the same object.

There are at least three ways to get the expected result:

1. Use the overload for `Assert.Equal()` that takes an argument of `IEqualityComparer<T>`.
2. Override the `Equals()` method of `ReferenceType`.
3. Skip `yield return` and use a collection that implements `IEnumerable` instead.

Arguably the first solution is the best since it does not change the implementation of `GetEnumerable()` or `ReferenceType`. In this case where `GetEnumerable()` is only used within the test I would opt for the third option as it is the easiest to do. It could look something like this:

```
IEnumerable<ReferenceType> GetData()
{
    return new[] { new ReferenceType() };
}
```

or this:

```
IEnumerable<ReferenceType> GetData()
{
    var referenceTypes = new List<ReferenceType>();
    // ... add reference types
    return referenceTypes;
}
```

This works since we are now iterating the collection that was created when we got the enumerable and not creating a new instance for each iteration.

Comment: Small nitpicky nitpick: It should perhaps be better "_The test fails since the default comparer for a reference type only checks if **object references** refer to the same object instance._"

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use to below function for problem solution.

```
public bool AreEquivalentEnumerator(IEnumerator<TSource> first, IEnumerator<TSource> second)
        {
            while (first.MoveNext())
            {
                if (!(second.MoveNext() && Equals(first.Current, second.Current))) return false;
            }

            if (second.MoveNext()) return false;

            return true;
        }
```